# No Start - 2015 Mazda6

Tags: starting

This is are my dashboard lights after the engine fails to start.

[image: 2015_Mazda6_nostart]

1. Power Steering Wheel.
2. Check Engine.
3. Battery.
4. Amber LED status on the Start button.

After the First try - It sounded like it tried to start.
After the second try and more - It tries to start just for a second and then just stops.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It ended up being the battery!

Got it replaced.